# MYSQL Query Help, Not Exists but also exists with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure if this is even possible but thought i'd put it out there. Is it possible to select records from one table that do not exists in another table but also records that may exists adding a condition? Here is the query right now.

```
SELECT first_name,last_name 
FROM clients 
WHERE clients.status = 'Active' 
    AND (NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * 
        FROM assignments AS c 
        WHERE c.client_id = clients.client_id ))
```

this will give me the records that dont exists, is it possible to add records that exists  with a condition? i.e I need to also see the records where assignments.active = 0

Comment: Can you share a sample of input table and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `active` condition to the subquery.

```
SELECT first_name,last_name 
FROM clients 
WHERE clients.status = 'Active' 
    AND (NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM assignments AS a
        WHERE a.client_id = clients.client_id 
            AND a.active = 1
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is good! now the problem is there may be multiple records in assignments for same client id and some may be active 1 and some active 0, I only need to show only if all records that exits are active = 0. I guess another way to describe it is I need to get all records from assignments that either not exists or only have active = 0. if client id (4) has 2 records in assignments 1 active = 1 and 1 active = 0 then that records should not be in the results

Comment: Then just add `AND a.active = 1` to the `NOT EXISTS` subquery.